# Too many re-renders on Antd treeNode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, antd

I'm using of Antd tree component in my react application.
at some point I needed to have custom titles so I added this feature by passing a custom component to "titleRender" prop available on Antd tree component.
Now the issues is when I open the tree (At any level) I get a crazy about of re-render on the treeNode component.=

Open the tree and check the logs [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-frost-6wm8i9?file=/src/App.js)

Is this a natural behavior?

```js
import { Tree } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
const treeData = [
  {
    title: "parent 1",
    key: "0-0",
    children: [
      {
        title: "parent 1-0",
        key: "0-0-0",
        children: [
          {
            title: "leaf",
            key: "0-0-0-0"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const Title = (props) => {
  console.log("render");
  return <h5>{props.title}</h5>;
};

export default () => (
  <Tree
    treeData={treeData}
    titleRender={(nodeData) => {
      return <Title title={nodeData.title} />;
    }}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to decrease the number of `titleRender` calls. For this you can set `motion` and `virtual` props to `false`. It could be something like that:

```
<Tree
    virtual={false}
    motion={false}
    titleRender={titleRender}
    treeData={treeData}
/>
```

I made simple [demo app](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-4-24-tree-titlerender-performance-5su6m) for that. We can see about 400-500 `titleRender` calls when we expand/collapse top node of the tree. If we then set `motion` and `virtual` props to `false`, we get about 10-30 `titleRender` calls.

Also, there is [an issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/34182) in Ant Design GitHub repository about `titleRender` performance.